# why can't I access a variable declared inside a class strait from the class

Tags: c#, class

what i mean is for example if i declare an int i inside a class like this:

```
class NewClass
{
int i;

}
```

I can't access it from the class like this:

```
class NewClass
{

int i;
i=5; //gives me an error
}
```

I tried making the 'i' variable static but it also didn't help (NewClass.i=5 also gave me an error).

Also another problem I encountered is this:

```
class NewClass
{
Board NewBoard2 = new Board();
public NewClass (Board NewBoard)
{
NewBoard2=NewBoard
}enter code here
//here I can't access nor NewBoard or NewBoard2
}
```

I didn't write code in quite a long time so that's why I have all those stupid questions..thanks for the help

Comment: Looks like you're trying to put code _outside_ a method. All your code (aside from field/property/method declarations) _must_ be placed within the scope of a method, property get/set implementation, or constructor. (there are a couple other cases I'm sure, but those are the main ones)

Comment: "I didn't write code in quite a long time so that's why I have all those stupid questions.." Hilarious! Shouldn't you then start by reading something? Just wondering...

Answer (score 2):

You cannot put statements (apart from declaration and declaration with assignment) directly in a class definition. Code needs to be in a method (or ctor, dtor, static initialiser block).

Answer (score 1):

You cant do this:

```
class NewClass 
{ 
int i; 
i=5; //gives me an error 
}
```

you would need a method inside the class for your code eg:

```
class NewClass 
{ 
 int i; 
 public void set_i()
 {
  i=5;
 }
}
```

So in your bigger class here:

```
class NewClass 
{ 
Board NewBoard2 = new Board(); 
public NewClass (Board NewBoard) 
{ 
NewBoard2=NewBoard 
}enter code here 
//here I can't access nor NewBoard or NewBoard2 
}
```

That wont work but

```
class NewClass 
{ 
Board NewBoard2 = new Board(); 
public NewClass (Board NewBoard) 
{ 
NewBoard2=NewBoard; 
// You can use NewBoard, or NewBoard2 here.
}

public void dostuff()
{
//You can use NewBoard2 here...
}
}
```